# permission issue for product author in woocommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce

I am using following plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-faqs.
If i click on the link received through mail by product author, to answer the question.
then it is displaying following message:
“Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.”

Is there any way we can give permission to product author to answer the question.

Do i need to use this:

```
function filter_woocommerce_options_prefix_answer_caps( $edit_post ) { 
    //......... 
    return $edit_post; 
}; 
add_filter( "woocommerce_answer_caps", 'filter_woocommerce_options_prefix_answer_caps', 10, 1 );
```

Thanks